# findByIdAndUpdate and recalculate average temperature

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have  a problem to do a query to mongo via Mongoose.

I push a new object on my array of object and I want to update the average value (of temperature field in my object in the array). Model:

```
var sensDaySchema= new mongoose.Schema({
date: {
    type:'date',
    required:true
},
avgTemperature:{
    type:'number',
    required:true
},
avgHumidity:{
    type:'number',
    required:true
},
dayDatas:{

    type:['object']

}})
```

i have started this with mongoose:

```
sensDayModel.findByIdAndUpdate(resultFind[0].id,{$push:{"dayDatas":args}},function(err,result){
            if (err) next(err,null)
            else{

                sensDayModel.aggregate({$group:{_id:resultFind[0].id,date:"$date",avgTemperature:{$avg:"$dayDatas.temperature"},avgHumidity:{$avg:"$dayDatas.humidity"},dayDatas:"$dayDatas" }},function(err,result){
                    result.save(function(err,result){
                        if (err) next (err,null)
                        else next (null,result)
                    })
                })
            }

        });
```

thanks in advance for answers!

Comment: Ok, and what is the problem? Is there something that doesn't work?

Comment: yes, it dowsnt work, but i found the solution :)